# What is the following Java/Android syntax actually doing?

Tags: java, android, permissions

I came across the following syntax, which is alien to me. I know String[] is a String array, but what are the curly braces doing

`new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}`

in the following code snippet:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
    }
```

Comment: It's creating a single element array on one line. Had you never seen `int[] arr = {1,2,3};` (or the long form `int[] arr = new int[] {1,2,3 };`) like you have here? The short form is only legal at declaration time.

Comment: You declare your needed permission inside Manifest and request for that permission and check it from your package manager cause every app has it own package manager with all permission.

Answer (score -1):

Calling this Android method displays a dialog box that prompts the app to grant permission and invokes onRequestPermissionsResult when the choice is made. Once this permission has been granted to the system, startAcquisition, stopAcquisition, and acquireGeoPosition are granted access to the location services.

```
new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}
```

For this syntax it an inline initializing for a list of string.